# Unable to resolve host address 'dl.google.com'

Tags: 20.04, firefox, google-chrome, wget

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I am unable to open the Firefox and Chrome browsers in the Ubuntu. I used `wget` command to install the browsers. However, `wget` command also did not work.

[image]

Comment: Firefox can be installed from the Ubuntu sources `sudo apt install firefox`
On the error message when trying to install Chrome: is the machine properly connected to the internet? Is the given URL correct?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20 release - Ubuntu release have always a version number consisting of four digits and a dot like 22.04. Please edit your question and state the correct version number you are using.

Comment: Make sure your internet is working, and if only the google site gives a problem, try again another time.

Comment: if it is not network problem; maybe you have a proxy configured. If so you have to define it in `/etc/wgetrc` too.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a disruption with the DNS server. To address this, you might want to switch to an alternative DNS server, I prefer `8.8.8.8` as it's the  **Google public DNS** which is a commonly used service.

**To do this**: Go to the settings and open the settings of your current network and then choose IPv4 and deactivate the Automatic option beside DNS. Then add this IP: `8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4` and click Apply.

This will be something like this (But maybe the GUI will be different as I use Ubuntu 23.10)
[image]